# Can regex in Python be used to ignore the case of just a SINGLE letter in an expression?

Tags: python, regex, string, case, expression

This is my first post, so hopefully I'm following protocols and not doing something too silly...

For this example, I ONLY want to return words that are four letters long, and the third letter is capitalized. the second and fourth letters are lowercase. The first letter can be EITHER upper or lower. I also HAVE to use regex.
For this example, I would only want two words to return, 'teSt' and 'ThIs':

`a = 'ThIs is a teSt of regex.'`

In Python I can easily ignore the case of a word using either the flag `re.I`:

`re.findall('[A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]',a,re.I)`

this returns:

`['ThIs', 'teSt', 'rege']`

or, I can use `(?i)`, like this:

`re.findall('(?i)[A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]',a)`

Which also returns:

`['ThIs', 'teSt', 'rege']`

Neither of these solutions work, because they blanket-ignore the case of the entire expression. Specifying each individual character with [a-z] or [A-Z] doesn't work either, because the first digit can be EITHER upper or lower.

so, essentially I want
`re.findall('[a-z OR A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]',a)`, but no matter what I try I cannot get that first letter `[a-z OR A-Z]` to work. Hope you can help!

Comment: Does `[a-zA-Z]` not work?

Comment: You can use `[A-Za-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]` without the `re.I`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to include in a separate answer the solution expressed in a comment by  @sj95126

[a-z OR A-Z] can be expressed as `[a-zA-Z]`

This will match a single character in the range between a and z or in the range between A and Z.